# How to rotate an array using array reversal technique?

Tags: arrays, scala

I am trying to rotate an array from a particular position using array reversal method.

Input array: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
d = 3
Output array: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

To achieve this I thought of working on the array in three steps.
Step1: Reverse the array from starting position until d => [4,3,2,1,5,6,7]
Step2: Reverse the array from d till the end of the array => [4,3,2,1,7,6,5]
Step3: Reverse the complete array from Step2 => [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

I haven't followed any functional programming pattern as I want to check the algorithm step by step.

```
  val arr = Array[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
  def reverseAlgo(brr: Array[Int], start: Int, end: Int): Unit = {
    var temp = 0
    for(i <- start until end/2) {
      temp = brr(i)
      brr(i) = brr(end-i-1)
      brr(end-i-1) = temp
    }
    brr.foreach(println)
  }
```

Step1 is working fine:

```
  reverseAlgo(arr, 0, 3)
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
4
5
6
7
```

But Step2 is not producing the required output:

```
  reverseAlgo(arr, 3, 7)
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
4
5
6
7
```

As you see, the output of the array should be: 3,2,1,7,6,5,4
Since the output from Step2 is incorrect, the final output is also wrong.

Step3:

```
reverseAlgo(arr, 0, arr.length)
```

Output:

```
7
6
5
4
1
2
3
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just something as simple as this?

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def rotate[T : ClassTag](arr: ArraySeq[T])(pos: Int): ArraySeq[T] = {
  val length = arr.length
  ArraySeq.tabulate[T](n = length) { i =>
    arr((i + 1 + pos) % length)
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
rotate(arr = ArraySeq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))(pos = 3)
// res: ArraySeq[Int] = ArraySeq(, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kgao7yHvRn2mPTXIPTSznw/9)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only work when the range starts at zero.

```
for(i <- start until end/2) {
  temp = brr(i)
  brr(i) = brr(end-i-1)
  brr(end-i-1) = temp
}
```

Should be something like:

```
for(i <- 0 until (end-start)/2) {
  temp = brr(start+i)
  brr(start+i) = brr(end-i-1)
  brr(end-i-1) = temp
}
```

With this change your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Mutation is to be avoided but, if you must, recursion is still useful.

```
def reversePart[A](arr: Array[A], start: Int, end: Int): Unit = {
  def loop(a:Int, b:Int): Unit =
    if (a < b) {
      val temp = arr(a)
      arr(a) = arr(b)
      arr(b) = temp
      loop(a+1, b-1)
    }
  loop(start max 0, end min arr.length-1)
}

val test = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
reversePart(test, 0, 3)   //Array(4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7)
reversePart(test, 4, 7)   //Array(4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5)
reversePart(test, -1, 99) //Array(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but for reference and for readers interested in a slightly different approach, one possibility is to implement this as a view.

In this example, `Rotate` implements the logic, while `IndexedSeqViewRotate` adds the `rotate` method as an extension to any `IndexedSeqView` as long as it's in scope.

In the tests, I materialized the views into `Vector`s to take advantage of the equality, but of course you can materialize them into an `Array` as well.

```
import scala.collection.IndexedSeqView
import scala.collection.IndexedSeqView.SomeIndexedSeqOps

final class Rotate[A](underlying: SomeIndexedSeqOps[A], n: Int) extends IndexedSeqView[A] {
  @inline private def rotateIndex(i: Int): Int = ((i - n) % length + length) % length
  override def apply(i: Int): A = underlying(rotateIndex(i))
  override lazy val length: Int = underlying.length
}

final implicit class IndexedSeqViewRotate[A](val underlying: IndexedSeqView[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def rotate(n: Int): IndexedSeqView[A] = new Rotate(underlying, n)
}

assert(Array().view.rotate(7).to(Vector) == Vector.empty)
assert(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).view.rotate(7).to(Vector) == Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
assert(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).view.rotate(0).to(Vector) == Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
assert(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).view.rotate(1).to(Vector) == Vector(7,1,2,3,4,5,6))
assert(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).view.rotate(3).to(Vector) == Vector(5,6,7,1,2,3,4))
assert(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).view.rotate(-1).to(Vector) == Vector(2,3,4,5,6,7,1))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/AC86kODlRLuBr0v8vWzVsA/87).